# How to write Matchers that match Matchers matching stuff

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, hamcrest

Ok, so I want to test my shiny new hamcrest Matchers.

Are there any Matchers that match custom Matchers matching or not matching stuff?
This would greatly help with writing tests for custom Matchers.

Comment: If you used the word "matcher" a bit more, it might be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you shouldn't need a `Matcher` for your `Matcher`. You should write a unit test and USES YOUR `Matcher`.

```
 @Test
 public void testPass(){
    assertThat(input, myMatcher);
 }


 @Test
 public void testFail(){
    assertThat(input, not(myMatcher));
 }
```

Rinse repeat for all cases you need to test.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the org.mockito.Matchers class to stub your input. There are many methods exposed by this class to use your stubbing.

- Matchers.anyString()
- Matchers.anyInt()
  etc..

Suppose you have one function in the class A as

```
class A{

public void loadFile(){
 file = new FileInputStream("/test/webapps/test.properties");
...
....
}
```

and you want to write a test case , you have to write as follow by using Matchers class for stubbing-

```
class Atest{
@Test
    public void testLoadFile()
       {
           final FileInputStream fileInputStreamMock = PowerMockito.mock(FileInputStream.class);
          PowerMockito.whenNew(FileInputStream.class).withArguments(Matchers.anyString())
                              .thenReturn(fileInputStreamMock);
}
```